# unable to convert bytes to string

Tags: python, bittorrent

I am trying to convert the `response` from `utorrent` dht network from `bytes` to `string` but I get `UnicodeDecodeError` errors

```
ping_query = {
    't': '0f',
    'y': 'q', 
    'q': 'ping',
    'a': {'id': client_id}}  

ping_query = bencode.encode(ping_query)
host = socket.gethostbyname('router.utorrent.com')
port = 6881

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
    s.connect((host, port))
    s.send(ping_query)
    r = s.recvfrom(1024)

response_data = bencode.decode(r[0])

print(response_data['ip'].decode('utf-8'))
```

However i get the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

example of `response_data['ip']`: `b'\xeb\xff6isQ\xffJ\xec)\xcd\xba\xab\xf2\xfb'`

Any thoughts?

**Edit:** This is the raw response from `r`: `b'd2:ip6:\x80j\xe4\x01\xea\xdb1:rd2:id20:\xeb\xff6isQ\xffJ\xec)\xcd\xba\xab\xf2\xfb\xe3F|\xc2ge1:t2:xd1:y1:re'`

Comment: The data is not UTF-8. I can't see any pattern in it that seems to indicate an IP address.

Comment: Hi @KlausD., i've added the raw response that I get from `r`. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's `bencode`?

Comment: Its a library: https://pypi.org/project/bencode.py/